# Sass issue : concatenating the elements

Tags: css, sass, vendor

I have a problem with sass concatenating the elements.
I want to obtain -webkit-calc to be written together like this :

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 6rem);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 6rem);
width: -o-calc(100% - 6rem);
```

Sass code:

```
$vendorlist: unquote("-webkit-") unquote("-moz-") unquote("-o-");
@mixin calcmixx($prop, $val) {
#{$prop}: calc(#{$val});
@each $pref in $vendorlist {
    #{$prop}:#{$pre} + calc(#{$val});
  }
}
```

Here is the method used to include the mixin in sass file:

```
.PromoTitle{ margin: 0 auto; @include calcmixx( width, '100% - 6rem');
```

CSS result:

```
.PromoTitle{
    width: calc(100% - 6rem);
    width: -webkit- +calc(100% - 6rem);
    width: -moz- +calc(100% - 6rem);
    width: -o- +calc(100% - 6rem);}
```

If I try to write without "+"

```
   #{$prop}:#{$pref} calc(#{$val});
```

This is the result:

```
width: calc(100% - 6rem);
width: -webkit- calc(100% - 6rem);
width: -moz- calc(100% - 6rem);
width: -o- calc(100% - 6rem);
```

And is I write it in this way there will be no result:

```
#{$prop}:#{$pref}calc(#{$val});
```

Comment: Why use prefixes when [calc() doesn't need them](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) for latest versions of modern browsers?

Comment: I found a problem which occurs on iPhone4

Comment: There is not enough code here to reproduce the problem.  We need to be able to take the code as is and compile it to get the exact results you're seeing (hint: if you can't reproduce it on [sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/), you haven't provided enough code).

Comment: I've added the method I used to include the mixin.

Comment: @Gabriel - seems to work in [sassmeister](http://s8.postimg.org/9b3xtmw9h/Screen_Shot_2015_10_01_at_14_42_54.png)?

Comment: yeah, on Sassmeister it works....

Comment: One of the options you already have works.  If you can't find a way to provide enough information to reproduce the problem, this question is going to end up closed.

Comment: The vendor prefixing problem has already been solved. There are a number of solutions which just work. Why re-invent the wheel, especially when it involves a bizarre language with weird symbols which no one can read, write, or debug?

Answer (score 0):

Sass code:

```
@mixin calcmixx($prop, $val) {
  @each $pref in -webkit-, -moz-, -o- {
    #{$prop}: $pref + calc(#{$val});
  } 
  #{$prop}: calc(#{$val});
}
```

Method used to include the mixin in sass file:

```
.PromoTitle {
    margin: 0 auto;
    @include calcmixx(width, '100% - 6rem');
}
```

It compiles to:

```
.PromoTitle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 6rem);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 6rem);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 6rem);
  width: calc(100% - 6rem);
}
```

The "vendor list" is really unnecessary

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get this to successfully compile with node-sass:

```
$vendorlist: -webkit-, -moz-, -o-;

@mixin calcmixx($prop, $val) {
  #{$prop}: calc(#{$val});
  @each $pref in $vendorlist {
    #{$prop}: #{$pref}calc(#{$val});
  }
}

.PromoTitle{
  margin: 0 auto;
  @include calcmixx(width, '100% - 6rem');
}
```

to this:

```
.PromoTitle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: calc(100% - 6rem);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 6rem);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 6rem);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 6rem); 
}
```

The `+`'s in your original question are unnecessary

Comment: The OP has not provided enough information here.  They claim that all of the things they've tried do not work (hint: the code you wrote actually appears in the OP, they claim "And is I write it in this way there will be no result").